# VPP applications failing to deploy due to invalid authentication token error 9622

Tags: ios, mdm, apple-vpp

I am trying to deploy VPP Apps from my MDM server but when I enter the VPP token I get invalid authentication token error 9622 and as a result the Apps are not showing up.

Comment: ...and you can't retrieve a new VPP token why?

Comment: @zaitsman The token wasn't accessible to me earlier but now I've access to it and after getting a new token it worked fine. Thanks !